# Counting the length of each branch in a binary tree and print out the nodes traversed

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to return the **length** of all the paths and the actual **paths** of a binary tree with the values ordered by the position of the leaf nodes from left to right.

For eg, for this binary tree (picture below), the answer should be `[(3, '4‐2‐1'), (4, '8‐5‐2‐1'), (4, '9‐5‐2‐1'), (2, '7‐1')]` because the paths to leaf nodes are "1‐2‐4" (length 3), "1‐2‐5‐8" (length 4) "1‐2‐ 5‐9" (length 4) etc.

[image]

I've tried using recursion (sample code below) to count the length of the path but keep getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`.

```
    res = []
    count = 0

    if T== None:
        return 0

    lengthL = 1 + self._pathV2(T.leftT)
    lengthR = 1+ self._pathV2(T.rightT)

    count = lengthR + lengthL
    res.append(count)
```

Any help with solving this problem will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide your complete code I couldn't create a coding example using your code.

I created a coding example by modifying code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-binary-tree-print-out-all-of-its-root-to-leaf-paths-one-per-line/ as follows.

```
class Node: 

    # A binary tree node has data, 
    # pointer to left child and a  
    # pointer to right child 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

def dfs_paths(stack, root, paths = []): 
    """ Depth first search through the tree for paths ensures paths are ordered 
        by the position of the leaf nodes from left to right """

    if root == None: 
        return

    # append this node to the path array 
    stack.append(root.data) 
    if(root.left == None and root.right == None): 

        # append all of its  
        # root - to - leaf 
        paths.append(' '.join([str(i) for i in stack[::-1]]))

    # otherwise try both subtrees 
    dfs_paths(stack, root.left, paths) 
    dfs_paths(stack, root.right, paths) 
    stack.pop() 

def paths_with_counts(root):
    """ Add counts to paths """
    paths = []
    dfs_paths([], root, paths)  # depth first search for paths

    # Add count to paths i.e. ('4-2-1') => (3, '4-2-1')
    return list(map(lambda p: (len(p.split()), p), paths))
```

**Example Usage**

*Generate Your Tree example*

```
root = Node(1); 
root.left = Node(2); 
root.right = Node(7);
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.left.right.left = Node(8)
root.left.right.right = Node(9)

print(paths_with_counts(root))
```

**Output**

```
[(3, '4 2 1'), (4, '8 5 2 1'), (4, '9 5 2 1'), (2, '7 1')]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Just to confirm - show_route(stack, root.left, paths)  should be replaced with dfs_paths(stack, root.left, paths)  instead right?

Comment: @entrynotfound--yes, sorry.  Yet another example why it's not a good idea to refactor code in response posting but always do it in the IDE then copy/paste to the posting.  I updated my answer with the proper code.